# creating a new column in a dataframe based on 4 other dataframes

Tags: python, filter, merge

Imagine we have 4 dataframes

```
df1(35000, 20)  
df2(12000, 21)
df3(323, 18)
df4(220, 6)
```

Here is where it is get tricky:

```
df4 was created by a merge of df3 and df2 based on 1 column.
It took 3 columns from df3 and 3 columns from df2.  (that is why it has 6 cols in total)
```

what I want is the following: I wish to create an extra column in df1 and insert specific values for the rows that have the same value in a specific column in df1 and df3. For this reason I have done the following

```
    df1['new col'] = df1['Name'].isin(df3['Name'])
```

Now my new column is filled with values True/False whether the value in the column name is the same for both df1 and df2. So far so good, but what I want to fill this new column with the values of a specific column from df2. I tried the following

```
  df1['new col'] = df1['Name'].map({True:df2['Address'],False:'no address inserted'})
```

However, it inserts all the values of addresses from df2 in that cell instead only the 1 value that is needed. Any ideas?

I also tried the following

```
merged = df2(df4, how='left', left_on='Name',right_on = 'First Name', indicator=True)
df1['Code'] = np.where(merged['_merge'] == 'both', merged['Address'], 'n.a.')
```

but I get the following error

```
Length of values (1210) does not match length of index (35653)
```

Comment: why can't you merge again? maybe using the ```how='left'```` parameter if you don't want to drop any missing rows?

Comment: Hey I also tried merging but I got an error. I will edit my question!

Comment: I think your error is with the 2nd line, you're attempting to update a series in df1. You probably want ```merged['Code'] = .....```. You're also missing a comma after the df4.

Comment: @el_oso i just didn t type it here correctly. My mistake. In my code the comma exists

Answer (score 0):

`merge` using the `how='left'` and then fill the missing values with `fillna`.

```
merged = df2(df4, how='left', left_on='Name',right_on = 'First Name', indicator=True)
merged[address_column].fillna('n.a.', inplace=True) #address column is the name or list of names of columns that you want the replace the nan's with
```

Comment: hey! I have tried that and right now it can identify which rows are in both dataframes correctly. However after the  merging process the merged dataframe is actually bigger than my original df1 and it throws an error